# Image formats of theme not recognized

Tags: sulu

I want to add Thumbnail-Settings for my theme.
I'm using the default theme for the moment.

There is already a image-formats.xml in the themes config.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<formats xmlns="http://schemas.sulu.io/media/formats"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.sulu.io/media/formats http://schemas.sulu.io/media/formats-1.0.xsd">
    <format>
        <name>640x480</name>
        <commands>
            <command>
                <action>resize</action>
                <parameters>
                    <parameter name="x">640</parameter>
                    <parameter name="y">480</parameter>
                </parameters>
            </command>
        </commands>
    </format>
    <format>
        <name>1200x</name>
        <commands>
            <command>
                <action>scale</action>
                <parameters>
                    <parameter name="x">1200</parameter>
                </parameters>
            </command>
        </commands>
    </format>
</formats>
```

The corresponding config looks like that:

```html
# LIIP Theme Configuration
liip_theme:
    themes: ["default"]
    active_theme: "default"
    load_controllers: false
```

If i dump the images in my assets the new format (the 1200x) is not shown.
I tried to reload the config and clear the cache. I also cleared the web/uploads/media folder.

What else can it be?

Here is the dump of the image in the template.
As you see, my own format is not appearing.

```js
Media {#2167 ▼
  #url: "/media/12/download/1.png?v=1"
  #formats: array:10 [▼
    "400x400" => "/uploads/media/400x400/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "400x400-inset" => "/uploads/media/400x400-inset/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "200x200" => "/uploads/media/200x200/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "190x" => "/uploads/media/190x/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "170x170" => "/uploads/media/170x170/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "150x100" => "/uploads/media/150x100/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "100x100" => "/uploads/media/100x100/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "100x100-inset" => "/uploads/media/100x100-inset/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "50x50" => "/uploads/media/50x50/02/12-1.png?v=1"
    "640x480" => "/uploads/media/640x480/02/12-1.png?v=1"
  ]
  #locale: "de"
  #version: null
  #additionalVersionData: array:1 [▶]
  #fileVersion: FileVersion {#2754 ▶}
  #file: File {#2751 ▶}
  #entity: Media {#2748 ▶}
}
FileVersionMeta {#2759 ▼
  -id: 12
  -title: "1"
  -description: null
  -copyright: null
  -locale: "de"
  -fileVersion: FileVersion {#2754 ▼
    -name: "1.png"
    -version: 1
    -size: 105564
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -storageOptions: "{"segment":"04","fileName":"1.png"}"
    -storageType: null
    -downloadCounter: 0
    -created: DateTime {#2742 ▶}
    -changed: DateTime {#2743 ▶}
    -id: 12
    -contentLanguages: PersistentCollection {#2761 ▶}
    -publishLanguages: PersistentCollection {#2763 ▶}
    -meta: PersistentCollection {#2758 ▶}
    -file: File {#2751 ▶}
    -tags: PersistentCollection {#2756 ▶}
    -changer: User {#2430 ▶ …2}
    -creator: User {#2430 ▶ …2}
    -defaultMeta: FileVersionMeta {#2759}
    -properties: "[]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe also add all the paths of the files? I think the error might be there.

Comment: Damn... this day it is working. I don't know why. Just restarted my vagrant box and now it works.
Thanks for your help thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image Formats are stored in the container by compiler pass in the `sulu_media.image.formats` parameter. When you add a new image format a cache delete for BOTH Kernels is needed.

```
app/console cache:clear -e yourenvironment
app/webconsole cache:clear -e yourenvironment
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there was a Caching problem. I already deleted the cache-folder, but it didn't work. I restarted my VM and now it works. Semms to be a problem on my side :-)